# Split an IP address into four separate values

Tags: c#, string

How do I split an IP address into four separate values?

**Example** if my ip is 192.168.0.1

Value1 = 192

Value2 = 168

Value3 = 0

Value4 = 1

Comment: What's your input - string / System.Net.IPAddress? Would you like the output as strings / bytes / int32s ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want the different parts then you can use

```
        string ip = "192.168.0.1";
        string[] values = ip.Split('.');
```

You should validate the IP address before that though.

Answer (score 10):

For IPv4, each octet is one byte.  You can use `System.Net.IPAddress` to parse the address and grab the array of bytes, like this:

```
// parse the address
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");

//iterate the byte[] and print each byte
foreach(byte i in ip.GetAddressBytes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

The result of the code is:

```
192
168
0
1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply call `.ToString()` and then `.Split('.');`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string ip = "192.168.0.1";
string[] tokens = ip.Split('.');
int value1 = Int32.Parse(tokens[0]);   // 192
int value2 = Int32.Parse(tokens[1]);   // 168
int value3 = Int32.Parse(tokens[2]);   // 0
int value4 = Int32.Parse(tokens[3]);   // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get them as an array of integer like the following:

```
int [] tokens = "192.168.0.1".Split('.').Select(p => Convert.ToInt32(p)).ToArray();
```

Good luck!